# Is the atrpms.net repository offline?

Tags: centos, repository

I can't manage to connect to atrpms.net for about a week now. I've tried using yum and browsing any of the websites. Nothing is responding, including the maillist.
Is it offline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is it offline?

Short Answer - Yes.

You can use [Is It Down Right Now?](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/) to check the status of any website.

> "Is It Down Right Now" monitors the status of your favorite web sites and checks whether they are down or not. Check a website status easily by using the below test tool. Just enter the url and a fresh site status test will be performed on the domain name in real time using our online website checker tool. For detailed information, check response time graph and user comments.

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/atrpms.net.html:

> Atrpms.net is DOWN for everyone. It is not just you. The server is not responding...

See also this question [Is atrpms dead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229661/is-atrpms-dead)